# Adding an extra check in MySQL query

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have the following code

```
 dbConn.query("REPLACE INTO entries SET ?", _mydata);
```

and I want to add an extra check, for limiting its activity to entries that have the value locked set to 1.

I tried something like

```
dbConn.query("REPLACE INTO entries SET ?", _mydata, "WHERE locked=1");
```

but it didnt work.

A conditional IF statement would work aswell but im really unsure if there is a way to achieve a ternary IF via dbConn.query.

Comment: Have you tried `dbConn.query("REPLACE INTO entries SET ? WHERE locked=1", _mydata);`?

Comment: @Molda suggestion should have worked, what module are you using?

Comment: @PedroSilva I am using Parser.js node module, stored in /node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js. When I replace the code with the one Molda added here, I get a Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE locked=1' at line 1

Comment: @JohnGreco What is _mydata? It should be an object.